# Managing git repository

Tags: git, teamwork, workflows

I don't know if I am over-complicating stuffs but here is our setup.

- 3 Code hosting servers (QA, Stage, and Production)
- 3 main git Branches (`dev`, `stage` and `master`) for respective servers
- 10-15 developers working on git sometimes working on same file concurrently.
- Developers are only allowed to merge and push to `dev`, Maintainers handle the code releases to stage and production.
- any issues are done in their own branch checked-out from `master` branch (sometimes from connected branch).
- each branches are merged individually to the main branches.
- issues or task has varied release dates so master is not always up to date. Sometimes one issue from dev can take months to go to master/production.

Currently we are facing quite a bit of code conflict issues on `dev`, which is also wasting lot of our time. Also the code history or graph as of now is starting to look like spider web.

Previously what we had was a linear setup where every one would commit to dev, then maintainers would cherry-pick the commits to stage or prod. That setup was easier for developers but nightmare for maintainers.

If any one has experience with this kind of setup, please advise on how did you made your work easier? I know communication is the key here, but without a dedicated person I find it really challenging right now.

Comment: aren't feature branch same as a common branch which multiple devs use?

Comment: Why, previously, were the maintainers cherry-picking commits? Did they only want certain work actually going through to production? Did they want work to go into production in a different order than it was completed in?

Comment: yeah, not all work goes to production. Sometimes one work can take months to go to production.

Comment: @Ruchan It sounds like you have some organisational problems, namely work not being prioritised correctly, and the rest of your development process is being contorted to work around this. Fix the root causes and the rest might fall into place.

Comment: That’s why you use feature flags. Developers can merge their code to master and maintainers turn the feature on via configuration when it’s ready to go live.You need to separate the concepts of merging code and releasing a feature.

Comment: @RubberDuck can you provide with an example repo or read i can look into?

Comment: are the devs using feature branches? do they merge the feature branch to dev before its been signed off for the next release?

Comment: do "Maintainers" change code?

Comment: This is pretty much the best blog on the topic I know of. https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html

Comment: I think we are already creating feature branches, but the feature flags are the ones that we have not tried.

Comment: @RubberDuck after reading the article I don't think thats a feasible route we want to take. It makes sense to have toggles, but it would add more complexity to writing code and managing releases.

Comment: if you are using feature branches, at what point do you get merge conflicts?

Comment: when you say "any issues are done in their own branch checked-out from master" do you mean they make a new branch from master or that they use their local version of master

Comment: @Ewan new branches are created from remote master. We mostly get conflicts while merging to `dev`.

Comment: @Ruchan more complex than dealing with merge conflicts and cherry-picking commits? Just food for thought.

Comment: merging to dev from where?

Comment: "It makes sense to have toggles, but it would add more complexity to writing code and managing releases" - my experience with it is quite the opposite. Feature toggles allow early merges, which avoids tons of problems, but without automatically making a half-baked feature visible to the world.

Comment: frankly i think feature flags are a nightmare. But they are preferable to merging in random subsets of code and hoping it works

Comment: Thank you guys for the help and suggestions, I will take these things into consideration and make change as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally clear on what your process is. But!

If you use feature and hotfix branches correctly you should only get merge conflicts when you actually have a conflict.

**Developers** branch from develop -> feature123 and build a feature, commiting the feature123 as they go.

When they are finished they merge from develop -> feature123 again to pick up any changes that have happened in develop form other features or hotfixes while they have been working.

Here, if someone has changed the same code as you, you will get a merge conflict. You will have to decide how your feature should work with the changed code.

Once the developer resolves the conflict they can merge feature123 -> develop

Once all the features for a release are finished you can merge form develop -> master

**Maintainers** branch from master -> hotfix123 and make changes in hotfix123. Once they are complete they merge hotfix123 into both master AND develop

Here they can get conflicts from other hotfixes which change the same code (hopefully rare) and from new features added by developers.

This will be the most difficult merge as the Maintainer and Developer are in different teams and will need to cooperate on the merge.

Comment: this method is goto method for sprint releases, where all changes in a sprint are released at once. For my case, as mentioned, we do selective release of features. All things in dev are not necessarily production ready.

Comment: hmm you might want to make that clearer in the question. also, dont merge to dev unless the feature is complete

Answer (score 0):

The developers should regularily merge `master` in, last time when done with the feature, and *only* merge back to master when their work is correctly integrated.  This ensures that `master` is always usable by others.

This is important to ensure they work against the latest released code.  It is in their own interest, so they should pick it up quickly.  It is much easier to do incremental merge fixes than waterfall merges.